# How to count the Number of click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using tooltip in my blog which is coded using CSS and HTML below is its code. I want to track the number of clicks made on tooltip box. Is there any way by which I can see the number of clicks made on it. If possible views should engrave in the box(corner) itself. This is the code of tooltip

```css
body{margin-top:50px}

.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ff5733;
    text-align:left;
}

.tooltip {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ff5733;
    text-align:left;
}

.tooltip .right {
    min-width:80px; 
    top:50%;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:20px;
    transform:translate(0, -50%);
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:#444444;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:13px;
    border-radius:8px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999999;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  border:3px solid #ff5733;box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    visibility:hidden; opacity:0; transition:opacity 0.8s;
}

.tooltip:hover .right {
    visibility:visible; opacity:1;
}

.tooltip .right i {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:100%;
    margin-top:-12px;
    width:12px;
    height:24px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.tooltip .right i::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:12px;
    height:22px;
    left:0;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
   border:3px solid #ff5733;box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class=" tooltip">trial view
        <span class="right toolTipWrap">
<a href="https://factsbyteinjournal.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-add-lazy-loader-for-images-in.html"><img alt="Lazy Loader" border="0" data-original-height="86" data-original-width="86" src="https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/coffee-resized.jpg"/></a>
              Read Now!
            <i></i>
        </span>
    </span>
```

Comment: Where do you want to keep track of these clicks, client or server side?

Comment: just I can view those click

Comment: That doesn't answer my question?

Comment: what you want to know I didn't get it.

Comment: Google Client Side vs Server Side, then answer the question :)

Comment: server-side, Now please write a code which will work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t write the code because I’m on my phone, but you should create a variable that’s stores the value for clicks, then you should add an event listener on the tooltip, then using the on click function you should increase the variable by 1. Then you can use the data from that variable that you made to display the number. Good luck, hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

Add `id="tooltip"` to the  tag and use this script. The `count` variable will hold the number of clicks and you can process it however you want.

```
window.onload=function(){
  var count = 0
  var el = document.getElementById('tooltip').addEventListener("click", 
  function() {
    count++

   console.log(count)
  });
}
```

Comment: Here's a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/17dfk93L/). If you're looking for hover on the `trial view` text to indicate counts then that's a different implementation.

Comment: You need a storage to be able to achieve that. You can use this [service](https://jsonstorage.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```js
var count=0;
$('#trialView').click(function(){
   count++;
   alert(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class=" tooltip">trial view
        <span class="right toolTipWrap" Id="trialView">
<a href="https://factsbyteinjournal.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-add-lazy-loader-for-images-in.html"><img alt="Lazy Loader" border="0" data-original-height="86" data-original-width="86" src="https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples-onlinejpgtools/coffee-resized.jpg"/></a>
              Read Now!
            <i></i>
        </span>
    </span>
```

Comment: how, can you explain

Comment: you are using (#trialview) word but it is just a text on which I have insert tooltip I will always change according to my need it not any specific id but just a text to visualize tooltip

Answer (score 1):

add a onclick attribute to your span

```
     <span   id="clickme" onclick="clickme()" class=" tooltip">trial view
        <span  class="right toolTipWrap">
        <a  href="https://factsbyteinjournal.blogspot.com/2019/04/ho 
   w-to-add-lazy-loader-for-images-in.html"><img alt="Lazy 
   Loader" border="0" data-original-height="86" data- 
    original- 
       width="86" 
     src="https://onlinejpgtools.com/images/examples- 
    onlinejpgtools/coffee-resized.jpg"/></a>
           Read Now!
         <i></i>
       </span>
    </span>

    <script>
   var click = 0;
   function clickme(){

       click++;
    alert(click);
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: Hey sorry, change the alert(count); to alert(click), my mistake and it should work, i just edited it. Please upvote my answer if it works.